# Application of the inclusion-exclusion formula (probability)

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be the colelction of permutations of the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ with the normalised counting measure: $$P(A) = \dfrac{\text{ number of permutations belonging to A }}{n!}$$

For each $i$, let $A_i = \{\sigma \in \Omega: \sigma(i) = i\}$ be the set of permutations fixing the element $i$. Find $P(A_1),P(A_1 \cap A_2),..., P(A_1 \cap .. \cap A_n)$ and use the inclusion-exclusion formula to find the probability that a permutation fixes no element.

I have calculated: $P(A_i) = 1/n$ for all $i$ and $P(\cap_i^k A_i) = \dfrac{(n-k)!}{n!}$. To find the probability a permutation fixes no element, I believe we want:

$$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n(A_i)^c\right) = 1 - P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)$$

Now I am supposed to use the inclusion-exclusion formula:

$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = \sum_i P(A_i) - \sum_{i<j}P(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum_{i<j<k}P(A_i\cap A_j \cap A_k) +... +(-1)^{n-1} P(A_1 \cap ... \cap A_n)$$

but I am having troubles understand what this formula means, for instance the final term of the formula: $$\sum_{i<j<k}P(A_i\cap A_j \cap A_k) +... +(-1)^{n-1} P(A_1 \cap ... \cap A_n)$$ what is this exactly, are we summing over i,j or k? Even so, I can't reach the final answer given.

Comment: For the $i\lt j\lt k$ part, we are in effect summing over all collections of three distinct numbers. There are $\binom{n}{3}$ such, and (as you wrote) for any such triple the term is $\frac{(n-3)!}{n!}$, so the contribution is $\binom{n}{3}\frac{(n-3)!}{n!}$, which simplifies to $\frac{1}{3!}$.

Comment: Note that the term after the one just discussed will be a sum $\sum_{i\lt j\lt k\lt l}$, **not** a sum over triples.

Comment: Ah i see what that terms means, thank you. Could you please elaborate on why there will be n choose 3 of these, for isntance in the firm term of the formula, there will be n choose 1 I am assuming - but why exactly?

Comment: For the first term, the $A_i$, there are $\binom{n}{1}$ ways to choose $i$. For the second term, where sum the probabilities that a permutation fixes $i$ and $j$, there are $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to choose the pair of elements that will be fixed.  For concreteness I suggest working with $n=4$ or maybe $5$. Then what's happening will likely become clear.

Comment: You are welcome.